# Create jitsi installer that use OSGI Framework

Tags: java, windows-installer, osgi, jitsi

I have problem to create installer for Jitsi, as i read article from [here](https://jitsi.org/index.php/Documentation/HowToBuildAnInstaller) , I didnt get anything exact way to make the installer.

Also i tried on ant built (it keep telling me that i dont have make.exe, where should I get this file??)

```
Buildfile: /Users/dejoong/workspace/eclipse-indigo/workspace/jitsi/build.xml
clean-install-windows:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/dejoong/workspace/eclipse-indigo/workspace/jitsi/release/windows
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/dejoong/workspace/eclipse-indigo/workspace/jitsi/release/windows/tmp
build-installation-wix-base:
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /Users/dejoong/workspace/eclipse-indigo/workspace/jitsi/release/windows/versionupdate.properties
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/dejoong/workspace/eclipse-indigo/workspace/jitsi/release/windows/tmp/light

BUILD FAILED
/Users/dejoong/workspace/eclipse-indigo/workspace/jitsi/resources/install/build.xml:403: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "make.exe" (in directory "/Users/dejoong/workspace/eclipse-indigo/workspace/jitsi/src/native/windows/run"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Anyone can help? or any article that talk about how to make installer form OSGI framework?

Thanks alot.

Comment: `make.exe` would be a Windows executable, whereas you appear to be running Linux or OSX. Whoever wrote this ANT build screwed it up badly.

Comment: Hi Neil, actually make.exe should be inside project workspace, which is I cant find. Anyway, I also try to run this from windows but it showed same result "make.exe No such file or directory" since i dont have it (the file). Btw, can u help me where to find the make.exe file? so im able to run it from windows. tx

Answer (score 0):

You need to download mingw with msys.
After that, rename mingw-make.exe to make.exe, and then set it in the PATH.

msys has the commands required for the build, and Mingw has Make and Gcc for you to build.